# Django: implement multiple user levels / roles / types

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, web

I have been using Django for quite a while but never have I thought of this until now.

Currently, I have a project that contains different user levels. Usually, in my past experience, I only developed systems using Django with only two user levels which are superuser and normal/regular user. So my question is **what are the effective ways to present these different user levels in the model/database?** Here, I'm going to use a school system as an example and also provide some of my initial thoughts on implementing it.

User levels:

1. Admin (superuser & staff)
2. Principal
3. Teacher
4. Students

Method #1: Add new tables based on each user level

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class User(AbstractUser):
    user = models.CharfieldField(max_length = 10, unique = True)

class Admin(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)

class Pricipal(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)

class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
```

Method #2: Add additional user types attributes in the User model

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class User(AbstractUser):
    user = models.CharfieldField(max_length = 10, unique = True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    is_principal = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default = False

'''
User table in DB:
user | is_superuser | is_staff | is_principal | is_teacher | is_student
'''
```

My thoughts:

In Method #1, as the built-in User model has two fields, is_staff and is_superuser, Is it possible to implement/change the fields into a SuperUser/Admin table as in the example above? This means that when I create an admin/superuser, I want it to add a new row into the Admin table, instead of adding a new user and updating the user's is_superuser and is_staff fields into 1 in the built-in User model.

In Method #2, the problem with it is that tables with different access privileges are directly connected to it. For example, Salary model (which cannot be accessed by Student user) has a direct link with the User model (contains Student user).

I hope I am able to get some insights and also a proper effective way of implementing this so that to prevent any implementation inconvenience and mistakes in the future. Thank you very much.

Comment: Do groups not satisfy your need? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#groups

Comment: @IainShelvington Isn't groups used for categorizing users based on access permissions?

Answer (score 9):

I think you are in the right path with method #2. It is lighter, and more straightforward.

I would not use a custom "user-like" model for each permission level. Over-complicated, does not scale, and multiply the number of queries, with no very benefit for your problem. **Not your UML schema but its content must guarantee your permission requirements**.

If the permission levels are not mutual-exclusive :

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField


class User(AbstractUser):
    ADMIN = 0
    PRINCIPLE = 1
    TEACHER = 2
    STUDENT = 3
    USER_LEVEL_CHOICES = (
        (ADMIN, "Admin"),
        (PRINCIPLE, "Principle"),
        (TEACHER, "Teacher"),
        (STUDENT, "Student"),
    )
    status = ArrayField(
        models.IntegerField(choices=USER_LEVEL_CHOICES, blank=True, default=STUDENT),
    )
```

But you need to have a wider reflexion.

---

I think you are talking about two separate problems : **polymorphism**, and **permissions**

- **Polymorphism** :

Polymorphism is the ability of an object to take on many forms. For a Django model, it can be done with many strategies : `OneToOneField` -as you mentioned-  **multi-table inheritance**, **abstract models**, or **proxy-models**.

Very good resources : this [article](https://realpython.com/modeling-polymorphism-django-python/), and Django doc about [model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.0/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance)

This very complex problem all refer to : **how much your several forms of a same entity are similar, or different. And which operations are particularly similar or different (data shape, querying, permission, ...etc)**

- **Permissions** design :

You can choose among several patterns

- **Model-oriented** permission : A user is granted "add", "view", "edit" or "delete" permission to a `Model`. *This is done in Django with the built-in `Permission` model, that have a ForeignKey to `ContentType`*
- **Object-oriented** permission : A user is granted "add", "view", "edit" or "delete" permission for each `Model` **instance.** Some packages provides this ability, `django-guardian` for example.
- **Rule-oriented** permission : A user is granted permission to a Model instance through custom logic instead of M2M table. The django `rules` package provide this kind of architecture.

Comment: How about if different user level has different functionalities (field)? For example, only  **Student** user-level model is required to upload the file (By using the FileField). Hence, isn't method#1 more preferable in this kind of situation?

Comment: In method #2, if you want to check the user permission before doing something, it will be easy to check `request.user.status` . Depending on that value, you raise Error or not, you perform action or not, ...

Answer (score 3):

You can create from AbstractUser (a full [User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User), complete with fields, including is_superuser and is_staff) a Profile and then, once you have the profile, give the chance of users to create other type of profile (Student, Teacher or Principle) which could have functionalities of its own.

For instances, in your models.py

```
class Profiles(AbstractUser):
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True, default=None, verbose_name=_(u'Date of birth'))
    principle = models.OneToOneField(Principles, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_(u'Principles'), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teacher = models.OneToOneField(Teachers, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_(u'Teachers'), on_delete=models.CASCADE)        
    student = models.OneToOneField(Students, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_(u'Students'), on_delete=models.CASCADE)  

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'profiles'
        verbose_name = _('Profile')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Profiles')
```

To that model you can add class methods, such as

```
def is_teacher(self):
    if self.teacher:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Then, your Teachers model could look like this

```
class Teachers(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(upload_to=UploadToPathAndRename(settings.TEACHERS_IMAGES_DIR), blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_('Teacher logo'))
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, default=None, max_length=255, validators=[MaxLengthValidator(255)], verbose_name=_('Name'))
    street = models.CharField( max_length=128, blank=False, null=True, default=None, verbose_name=_('Street'))
    created_by = models.ForeignKey('Profiles', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Comment: Great, but shouldn't the foreign key field be in the Teacher class (User type class)?

Comment: Sure, just added @Kyle_397

Comment: In this solution, you will have to add a new table each time you want to add another user-status. It does not scale at all. And you make extra queries between these many models, without a very benefit

Comment: Where are you seeing the status here @TimothéDelion? This would be like creating a company and having certain functionalities associated with that company.

Comment: I mean that `Teacher` is a "kind of" User, as `Student` and 'Principal' are too. They would probably have more things in common than different. In these case, I think it is more relevant to keep a unique model, with some "kind-specific" logic rather than multiply the DB tables

Comment: Depends really on the objectives. If one wants to be able to be a teacher and student at the same time, this way would be easy to create both teacher and student profile. The opposite is also true. What do you have against having more tables?

Comment: My answer is OK with being teacher and student at the same time, and the method#2 from @Kyle_397 too. More tables = more requests or at least more joins : it is costful. This is my Bible about polymorphism, tell me if you find it interesting too : https://realpython.com/modeling-polymorphism-django-python/

Answer (score 2):

One of the methods that I used in several projects is this (pseudo code):

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    ADMIN = 0
    PRINCIPLE = 1
    TEACHER = 2
    STUDENT = 3
    USER_LEVEL_CHOICES = (
        (ADMIN, "Admin"),
        (PRINCIPLE, "Principle"),
        (TEACHER, "Teacher"),
        (STUDENT, "Student"),
    )
    user_level = models.IntgerField(choices=USER_LEVEL_CHOICES)


def lvl_decorator():
  def check_lvl(func):
    def function_wrapper(self, actor, action_on, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'action_lvl' not in action_on: # then action_on is user
            if actor.user_lvl < action_on.user_lvl:
                return True
            return False
        else: # then action_on is action of some kind for that user (you can add action_lvl to ... and pas them to this wapper)
            if actor.user_lvl < action_on.action_lvl:
                return True
            return False
    return function_wrapper
  return check_lvl
```

Then you can write wrapper function with this logic for any action check if action level is bigger than user level e.g.: if someone wants to change superuser password he/she should be logged-in with level-0-user but for changing normal user's password he/she should be level 0, 1. This logic also can be applied to class, functions, etc actions.

Create base class and then add `lvl_decorator` to it then inherent from it => this keeps your code super clean and prevents further copy paste.

example of what i mean:

```
def lvl_decorator():
    def check_lvl(func):
        def function_wrapper(self, actor, action_on, *args, **kwargs):
            if 'action_lvl' not in action_on:  # then action_on is user
                if actor.user_lvl < action_on.user_lvl:
                    return True
                return False
            else:
                if actor.user_lvl < action_on.action_lvl:
                    return True
                return False

        return function_wrapper

    return check_lvl


class BaseClass(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, local):
        for attr in local:
            value = local[attr]
            if callable(value):
                local[attr] = lvl_decorator()
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, local)


# in other locations like views.py use this sample
class FooViewDjango(object, ApiView): # don't remove object or this won't work, you can use any Django stuff you need to inherent.
    __metaclass__ = BaseClass

    def baz(self):
        print('hora hora')
```

Use this base class in any where you want.

Comment: The idea seems interesting, with the wrapper function. Can you provide some reference or documentation regarding how to use it since I'm not very familiar with this :-(

Comment: @Kyle_397 i came out with this idea my self i didn't copy that from any where so there is no reference! but it works like charm!

Comment: @Kyle_397 i added sample as well Hope you can use it  now :D.