# Custom permissions for different user types django rest framework

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

For Django-reactjs project, I have a user model in django which has 3 boolean fields (is_admin, is_moderator, is_normal_user), and I also have 3 other models, I want to set permissions for each user type. The user can only create objects for 1 model only, the moderator is the only one that can edit a certain model field, and admins can do everything.

It might be a trivial question but I am a newbie in Django and React so If you could please tell me how can I handle it with custom permissions(some steps to follow) and also how these permissions are handled from React.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this has been discussed before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61040342/django-implement-multiple-user-levels-roles-types

Comment: You can have a look at this link from documentation. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization

Also, bear in mind that you can transform the permission as endpoint but I dont know whether is what you are looking for.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the user has permission every time he is making an action, so when the React app calls your Django API, it will provide an authentication token right? That tokens corresponds to a unique user, so you can just do an if statement:

```
if request.user.is_admin:
    do_everything()
elif request.user.is_moderator:
    do_other_stuff()
```

While in the react app you would need the information if the logged in user is a moderator, admin or a normal user, so you can display the pages accordingly. To get that info, you may want to implement a '/me' endopoint that returns info about the logged in user, containg his status.

If you have no idea what Im talking about, I strongly recommend you to take a look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0d7cIfiydAc

The whole subject is too long for a stackoverflow answer.

Contact me if you still have any doubts.